# Содержимое сайта, при уменьшении масштаба смещается влево

Tags: html, css, выравнивание, центрирование

Почему то прижимается к левому краю. Как сделать, чтобы по центру было?[image: Результат]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: 100;

}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: 300;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: 500;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: 700;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: 900;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Natasha';
  src: url('../fonts/Natasha.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/Natasha.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/Natasha.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/Natasha.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/Natasha.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/Natasha.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 940px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat;
  width: 1920px;
  min-height: 848px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 55px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header__logo span {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.header__menu_list li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 47px;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.header__main_menu div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.header__main_menu_mail {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 55px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.header__menu_list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.header__menu_list_item1 {
  margin-left: 175px;
}

.header__main_menu ul {
  ++-4margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__main_menu">
      <div class="header__logo">
        <span>my</span>portfolio
      </div>
      <div class="header__menu_list">
        <ul>
          <li class="header__menu_list_item header__menu_list_item1">
            <a href="#">ОБО МНЕ</a>
          </li>
          <li class="header__menu_list_item">
            <a href="#">НАВЫКИ</a>
          </li>
          <li class="header__menu_list_item">
            <a href="#">РАБОТЫ</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="header__main_menu_mail">
        info@myname.com
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__heading">
      <h1>ДЕЛО, КОТОРЫМ Я ЖИВУ</h1>
      <h2>ВЕРТСКА & FRONTEND</h2>
      <img src="img/header_image.png" alt="png">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, у вас `body` фиксированной ширины `940px` а `header` в нём шириной `1920px` который вы пытаетесь выровнять по центру с помощью `margin: 0 auto;`

Уберите фиксированную ширину для `body` и `header`, тогда блок с классом `.header` встанет по центру